# Python list creation with multiple loops

Tags: python, list

lets say I have one list ['A','B','C']

and the second [1,2]

I want to create a new list [(A,1), (A,2), (B,1)...]

Obviously it can be trivially done using a for loop like this:

```
a = ['A','B','C']
b = [1,2]
c = []
for x in a:
    for y in b:
        c.append((x,y))

c
[('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 1), ('C', 2)]
```

but how can I do it using the [x for x in...] syntax ?

Answer (score 4):

You need the **Cartesian Product** of the two lists:

```
>>> from itertools import product

>>> list(product(a, b))
[('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 1), ('C', 2)]
```

Unlike an explicit list comprehension, this is trivially scalable to any number of input iterables. See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at `itertools.product`:

```py
>>> from itertools import product
>>> a = [ 'A', 'B', 'C' ]
>>> b = [ 1, 2]
>>> [ x for x in product(a, b) ]
[('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 1), ('C', 2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using python lists:

```
[(i, j) for i in a for j in b]
```

Using a module:

```
from itertools import product

list(product(a, b))
```

Answer (score 2):

`[x for x in...]` syntax has name and it called list comprehension, you can write your loops between `[` and `]` and put inner most before your loops.

```
[(x, y) for x in a for y in b]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case the [list comprehensions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/) version could be:

```
>>> [(x, y) for x in "ABC" for y in [1,2]]
[('A', 1), ('A', 2), ('B', 1), ('B', 2), ('C', 1), ('C', 2)]
```

Note that the order matters, that is for a fixed `x='A'` the possible values of `y` are iterated first.